# Find absolute maximum and minimum values by parametrizing the boundaries

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = 2\cos x + 3\sin y$  $; R= {(x , y): 0 \leq x \leq 2\pi \\\mbox{and}\\ 0 \leq y \leq \pi} $

I need to find the absolute maximum value and absolute minimum value in the region $R$, and I do have to parametrize the boundary pieces of $R$ to find critical points there.

I tried taking $(x,y) = (r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$
and then I got $h(\theta) = 2\cos(r\cos(\theta))+3\sin(r\sin(\theta))$

After that $h'(\theta)=2r\sin(\theta)\cdot\sin(r\cos(\theta))+3r\cos(\theta)\cdot(\cos(r\sin(\theta))$.

I can't find values of $\theta$ for which $h'(\theta)=0$.

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: All you need is that $-1 \le \cos x \le 1$ and $0 \le \sin y \le 1$ on the given intervals.

Comment: @dxiv I am bit confused because of that r. I kind of get it, but I just can't write it in the form of an answer.

Comment: $2 \cdot (-1)+3 \cdot 0 \le 2\cos x + 3\sin y \le 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 1\,$ on $\,R\,$, and both equality cases are attained, so those are the absolute minimum, respectively maximum, values.

Comment: @dxiv I think the method you are using is without parametric boundaries. The question specifically asked to do it using the parametric method.

Comment: There is no need (and indeed no point) to parametrize the boundary in this very simple case. But if you *have* to do it, then see for example [Question on parametrization of the boundary of a rectangle in $\;\mathbb R^2\;$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588892/question-on-parametrization-of-the-boundary-of-a-rectangle-in-mathbb-r2). `I tried taking (x,y)=(rcos(θ),rsin(θ))` That's the parametrization of a circle, not a rectangle.

Comment: @dxiv thanks a lot for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the parameterizations

$$
x = \pi(1+\sin (u))\\
y = \frac{\pi}{2}(1+\sin (v))
$$

we have

$$
f(u,v) = 3 \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sin (v)\right)-2 \cos (\pi  \sin (u))
$$

so the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 \pi  \cos (u) \sin (\pi  \sin (u))=0 \\
 -\frac{3}{2} \pi  \cos (v) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sin (v)\right)=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving the solutions

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & f \\
 \pi  & -\frac{\pi }{2} & -2 \\
 \pi  & \frac{\pi }{2} & -2 \\
 \pi  & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -\frac{\pi }{2} & 2 \\
 0 & \frac{\pi }{2} & 2 \\
 2 \pi  & -\frac{\pi }{2} & 2 \\
 2 \pi  & \frac{\pi }{2} & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 2 \pi  & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

[image]